# Include php/html code or use function instead?

Tags: php, html, function, include

I am trying to figure out which is the best way to include some html/php code on some pages. For example header/footer and a couple other parts which are repetitive.

Should I include_once(php file) (which might be used multiple times in a single page) or use a function and grab the code from there?

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: You don't need to make a function to include code u can just use build in `php` function `include 'header.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions: **require 'file.php'**, **require_once 'file.php'**, **include 'file.php'**, **include_once 'file.php'** direct in your code html or php.... Example of use:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="menu">
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

> Use require when the file is required by the application.
>
> Use include when the file is not required and application should
>   continue when file is not found.
>
> Use _once for load the file only ONCE